# Extra line is displaying after longest line

Tags: html, css

I have the following output in a webpage (the black highlighted areas contain sensitive data):

[image: Provider Screenshot]

Each of the lines display correctly except for that the longest line always has another blank line after it.

Here's the code that represents a line:

```
<div style="clear:both; white-space:nowrap;">
    <span style="float:left; margin-right:5px">
    <a class="provider" href="javascript:void(0)" 
        onkeypress="showProviderInfo(this, 'claim2')"
            onclick="showProviderInfo(this, 'claim2')">[+]</a>
    THE ENTRY WITH THE LONGEST NAME CAUSES AN EXTRA LINE TO DISPLAY BELOW IT...
    </span>
    <span style="float:right">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"
        onkeypress="openAddWindowForMedicalProvider('12345678')"
        onclick="openAddWindowForMedicalProvider('12345678')">
    Create as Medical Provider
    </a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"
        onkeypress="openAddWindowForServiceProvider('12345678')"
        onclick="openAddWindowForServiceProvider('12345678')">
    Create as Service Provider
    </a>
    </span>
</div>
<br />
```

How can I style this such that the extra line doesn't show up after the longest one?

Comment: Without the stylesheet and a full standalone example I can't be sure, but is the 5px right margin (span = inline?) wrapping to the next line?

Comment: Show us the css or make a jsfiddle

Comment: CSS is posted - it's all inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me using jsfiddle.net

However, you both have `</ div>` and `<br />`. A `div` automatically gets a new line so the `br` is redundant and may be causing your issues.

Also, `<span style="float:left; margin-right:5px">` may be causing issues.  Floats and margins don't always do what you expect.  Maybe change it to `padding-right` or seeing what happens if you remove the spacing entirely and just put in a couple `&nbsp;` to see if that works.

You shouldn't need to float that span left anyway.

It may also be helpful to test this in multiple browsers.  It may be a browser thing.  IE is probably going to mess stuff up that works correctly in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I think the <br /> is indeed the issue.  I removed that and all of the spacing between lines is even.  Now, however, there's a gap after EVERY line whereas all of the lines were flush to each other except for the longest one when I had the <br />.

Comment: You can adjust that with a negative bottom margin.  Have you tried using firebug for firefox?  It will let you play with the css on a page to get it to look the way you want.  It will also help you figure out why the spacing is the way it is.

Comment: I'm developing strictly for IE 8 (ugh)...I've heard a lot about firebug and it looks like a nice tool.

Comment: The negative bottom margin and removal of the <br /> did the trick - thanks.

Comment: Awesome.  FYI, for IE - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359 AND http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a `<span>` can't be floated unless it's explicitly set to `display:block;`… right?